# HTTP 403 with django form submission only on IE9

Tags: django, internet-explorer, nginx

I'm working on Django version 1.4.2.
I've implemented this simple form example (inspired from djangobook) :

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from mysite.contact.forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                cd['subject'],
                cd['message'],
                cd.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
                ['siteowner@example.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})

# contact_form.html

<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contact us</h1>

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            {% csrf_token %}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

# forms.py

from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    message = forms.CharField()
```

Everything just work fine for all browsers i've tried (chrome, maxthon, firefox) but in IE9, i get a HTTP 403 refused.

Any clue about what's causing that ?

EDIT : after deeper investigations, I found that the problem comes from this : when asking the empty form, the navigator receives the csrf cookie, but for an unknown reason, it doesn't send back this cookie when posting the form. This problem seems to arise only when the cookie comes from the nginx server at pythonanywhere.com , when I test from an apache server of my own, cookie is sent back ok.

Here are the two headers captured from servers :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.5
Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2012 13:56:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=1AJjzkbUgJdKAmkbiHicJ3or2Mfi6AbD; expires=Wed, 20-Nov-2013 13:56:31 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2012 13:56:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=2iMZSH1s0vJnEt4tRRY7FciT1Q7orrVF; expires=Wed, 20-Nov-2013 13:56:50 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Keep-Alive: timeout=180, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The only significant difference seems to be the Kee-Alive header from apache...

Do you think it can comes from there ?

Answer (score 2):

`{% csrf_token %}` outputs a `<input type="hidden" ...>` tag, and maybe IE9 ignores it because it's a direct child of the table, instead of being inside a cell.

Try to move `{% csrf_token %}` just next to `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: Great catch, if that's the fix.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but that doesn't change a thing... I've tried before and after the submit. I've also tried relative and absolute paths in the "action" attribute of the form...

Comment: Maybe it's cookie related then. Check the headers that are being sent. Also, I figure it's a csrf protection issue ( which yields a 403 if it doesn't match ), but you do not explicitly mention if it's the error message you get.

Comment: Thanks vincent, I also guess it's this kind of issue. Meanwhile, i've digged deeper with wireshark, and found that the issue is also server-side related. I made my tests on pythonanywhere.com, which uses nginx as server. The same test with a dedicated server using apache won't cause the problem. So perhaps the problem is mostly from nginx...

Answer (score 0):

In Django's ticket [#17157](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17157) it's stated that the problem is that Internet Explorer blocks third-party cookies by default. So you can enable third-party cookies for all sites or only for your site in browser settings.
Here is how to do that in IE 7 (from [this link](http://feedjit.com/static/howToEnableThirdPartyCookies.html)):

1. Click the "Tools" menu
2. Click "Internet Options"
3. Select the "Privacy" tab

Option 1: To enable third-party cookies for all sites

1. Click "Advanced"
2. Select "Override automatic cookie handling"
3. Select the "Accept" button under "Third-party Cookies" and click "OK"

OR

Option 2: To enable third-party cookies just for Feedjit.com

1. Click "Sites"
2. Add "*your-domain.com*" and click "Allow"
3. Click "OK"
4. Select the "Accept" button under "Third-party Cookies" and click "OK"